# Consuming .net rest api via android - 400 error

Tags: android, asp.net, json, rest

I have created REST service according to this: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations
tutorial and a android client according to this: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/calling-restful-services-from-your-android-app/
I changed the service to receive the json messages, and the connection string to the same that works in the browser, with 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost(according to one of the advices in stackoverflow) - in the browser it works perfectly. When I try to test it on the emulator I get the 400 bad request error. Maybe this is totally wrong way of approaching this, I am confused - would you kindly show me the error in the implementation or the tutorial that could help me with consuming the rest api with android client?